# How to split a html table into two parts?

Tags: html, css, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular7

I want to show the data in a table format into two parts (left & Right). for example i a have a data of 20 rows. i need to display the first 10 rows into left side with header. remaining 10 rows need to display in right side with same header like image below, and i want to apply the pagination for the both table. how can i achieve this.

please help me, thanks in advance.

[Image (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPH8P.png)

```js
tableData = [{name:'abc',phone:1111},{name:'xyz',phone:1111},{name:'mno',phone:1111},{name:'pqr',phone:1111}]
```

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData; let i = index">
                                    <td><span>{{i+1}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.name}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.phone}}</span></td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData; let i = index">
                                    <td><span>{{i+1}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.name}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.phone}}</span></td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <app-pagination [size]=" (tableData).length " [items]="Items "></app-pagination>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a style with "display:flex". Hope this helps to print the two tables side by side.

As per the comments, please refer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

```js
tableData = [{name:'abc',phone:1111},{name:'xyz',phone:1111},{name:'mno',phone:1111},{name:'pqr',phone:1111}]
```

```html
<div class="row" style="display:flex">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData; let i = index">
                                    <td><span>{{i+1}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.name}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.phone}}</span></td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData; let i = index">
                                    <td><span>{{i+1}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.name}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{data.phone}}</span></td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <app-pagination [size]=" (tableData).length " [items]="Items "></app-pagination>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: I want to use the one table both sides. just i want show some records in left and some records in right.

Comment: Then it has to be under one single table tag having 'x' columns, to continue having 2x columns. Populate the values accordingly. In case of your example, you will end up having 6 columns in a single table. However, you can use loops to have one table tag printed twice having different values in them, under the style display:flex

Comment: Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

Comment: I got it, i tried by using slice filter *ngFor="let data of tableData |slice:0: tableData.length/2"  for table one.  *ngFor="let data of tableData |slice: tableData.length/2 : tableData.length" for table two.

Comment: Nice.. Glad that helped